# TensorFlow, TypeError: random_normal() got an unexpected keyword argument 'partition_info'

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, tensorflow, convolution

When running this piece of code (first convolution layer in TensorFlow model):

```
conv2d_layer_one = tf.contrib.layers.convolution2d(
    float_image_batch,
    num_outputs = 32, 
    kernel_size = (5, 5), 
    activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
    weights_initializer = tf.random_normal, 
    stride =(2, 2),
    trainable= True
)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: random_normal() got an unexpected keyword argument 'partition_info'
```

The tf.random_normal function doesn't take in any arguments such as partition_info so I'm somewhat confused as why this error is popping up.

I removed the weights_initializer argument and the error disappears. If I reintroduce it the error seems to appear again.

Answer (score 3):

Add this function definition before the convolution function:

```
from tensorflow.python.ops import random_ops

def _initializer(shape, dtype=tf.float32, partition_info=None):
     return random_ops.random_normal(shape)
```

And just call _initializer instead of tf.random_normal.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add() after `tf.random_normal`

```
weights_initializer = tf.random_normal()
```